# Field representations - problem with differential

Tags: special-relativity, coordinate-systems, field-theory, inertial-frames

So when we talk about scalar fields in spacetime, we set that  $\phi(x) \rightarrow \Lambda\phi(x)\equiv\phi'(x'). $ So that in the same event, the field value is the same for different frames $\phi'(x')=\phi(x).$ Maggiore then present:
$$\delta_0\phi(x)=\phi'(x)-\phi(x);$$ in my understading this means that we are looking for the difference between the value of the field function before the tranformation in a labeled point $x^\mu$, say event $P$, and the value of the tranformed field function in the same labeled point $x^\mu$ but in the same frame, but that label would mean a diffente event point in the transformed frame, say $P'$.

$\textbf{I'd like to know if this interpretation is the right one.}$

If $x^\mu\rightarrow x'^\mu=x^\mu+\delta x^\mu$ , thus:
$$\delta_0\phi(x)=\phi'(x'-\delta x)-\phi(x)=-\partial_\rho\phi'(x')\delta x^\rho=-\partial_\rho\phi(x)\delta x^\rho$$
since we are dealing in the same initial frame with the funcional difference.

But when I move to the Weyl field $\psi_{L,R}(x)$: $\psi'_L(x')=\Lambda_L\psi_L(x).$ Then again
$$\delta_0\psi_L=\psi'_L(x)-\psi_L(x)=\psi'_L(x'-\delta x)-\psi_L(x)$$
then since we are in the initial frame analysing functional modifications, as in the scalar field:
$$=\psi'_L(x')-\psi_L(x)-\partial_\rho\psi'(x')\delta x^\rho=\big(\Lambda_L-1)\psi_L(x) - \partial_\rho(\Lambda_L\psi_L(x))\delta x^\rho$$
but in the textbook the $\Lambda_L$ don't show up in the last term, so it put my interpretation in doubt:
$$=\big(\Lambda_L-1)\psi_L(x) - \partial_\rho\psi_L(x)\delta x^\rho$$
I was thinking that if the gradient was made in the transformed frame, the using chain rule, I could recover a inverse transformation and then cancel out this $\Lambda$ above, but that would go agains my interpretation. So I don't know where is my error.

There is a similar question about this last issue, but the answer that was given is appealling to infinitesimal $\Lambda_L$ ([Field transformations](https://physics.stackexchange.com/q/161449/)) so it doesn't quite help me.